# Reshaping Matlab Matrix

Tags: matlab

I am a Matlab novice and imagine the following is simple however I am stumped with the below.  I need to reshape a 315693x1838 matrix.  Below is an example of how it needs to be reshaped:

19 20 21 22 23
10 11 12 13 14
13 14 15 16 17

As

19 20 10 11 13 14
21 22 12 13 15 16
22 23 13 14 16 17

Is there a simple command for this as I cannot find one?

Thank you

Comment: There is: `reshape`. But you have to transpose it first: `reshape([1 2; 3 4; 5 6].',1,[])`. Or `a=[1 2; 3 4; 5 6]; a=a.'; a(:).'`. Take a look at the "Getting Started" part of the matlab documentation.

Comment: Your edit changes the question almost completely, and doesn't make sense (I see two occurences of a lot of numbers in there).

Answer (score 2):

MatLab is great and most of the functions do what they say.

```
M = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]

reshape(M', 1, 6)
```

For more details just

```
help reshape
```

Comment: Or `reshape(M', 1, [])` to [avoid a magic number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)

Comment: You're right! It's mentioned in reshape's help.